# Oracle ADF: How to design Login and Automatic Login features for adf web app

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am developing a web application using ADF (jdeveloper 11.1.2.4).

I need to know two things.

1. How to design login functionality. I have a login form user enters username and password then he clicks login button then what should I do. Do I have to use managed bean and validate the credentials and get the session object in that managed bean and put this credentials in session and use whenever I needed. For this I should use a task-flow with loginPage and a router and validAdminPage and a managed bean. Or Does ADF provides any built in functionality for this? for login process.?
2. In this I need to design  a  feature like once a user has logged in using valid credentials and he close the tab(not the browser),then again if he enter the /faces/login.jsf url means he is trying to login again but that is not necessary. After typing the url for login, He should automatically get the homepage.jsf (Automatic Login).

How to design these features

pleas Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using ADF Security? It provides all the things you want out of the box.

Comment: Actually am using ADF Essentials. So I cannot user ADF Security. . . Could you provide any alternative.

Comment: Check this blog: http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/adf-essentials-security-implementation.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: This is about Autherisation and authentication. Can you please give me answers for my two doubts.

Answer (score 0):

For ADF essentials, I implemented a project using open source IAM framework ***IAMFortress***. Now it is part of the Apache Directory project.

[Apache Fortress](https://directory.apache.org/fortress/).

It is a great product and supports ***RBAC*** and ***ARBAC*** spec. You can check out the tutorials that I wrote on this. It is a four part series. The tutorials cover authentication,authorization, custom EL expressions using custom EL Provider.

[Fortress with ADF Essentials:Part 1](http://ramannanda.blogspot.in/2014/01/driving-security-for-adf-essentials.html)